# Getting all hex colors to export to png

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, illustrator-scripting, rgb, script

I'm doing something kinda silly where I actually do need all ~16mil RGB colors. I do know how to do them separately, one by one, but I can imagine that taking quite a long time to do it manually.

This is what I have done manually so far: [image: at least 130 artboards with one unique RGB color each]

I'm hoping I don't have to continue doing this. If there is a source where I can get all RGB colors in hex value at a certain size (64px * 64px would be great) in one step, that would be lovely. I also don't mind if this would have to contain coding (Javascript would be best). I'm not sure how to make actions via js.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: An image containing a 64x64 block of each RGB colour would have a total of almost 70 billion pixels. What on EARTH would you want to do with an image that large?

Comment: @r3mainer Oh, no, I'm not planning on making one image with this. I actually need to export each 64*64 as different png files.

Comment: You want 16 million separate files? You could probably do this with ImageMagick

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What is the "something kinda silly" that you actually need this for?  Hexadecimal colours are RGB colours. Currently this question reads like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @BillyKerr Sorry, I apologize, maybe I'm more used to other stack exchange forums. I need this to directly have those 16mil files, each having different rgb solid color only. I unfortunately _must_ have those 16-17mil files, at least temporarily.

Comment: I agree with @BillyKerr; you probably don't need all these files. If they're only required temporarily, it would make more sense to write a program that creates these files on the fly whenever necessary. Surely you don't need all of them at the exact same moment?

Comment: @leguchi - if you only need them temporarily, then you don't need 16 million files. I am not a coder, but I would imagine it would be trivial to create any one of these colours programatically (on the fly as r3mainer suggests) for what ever purpose you need them for . . . which you still haven't mentioned.

Comment: @BillyKerr I need them temporarily, but all together. This is for a Minecraft mod.

Comment: @leguchi - I think this is off-topic. Not a graphic design question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @BillyKerr Oh, I apologize. I thought we were able to make scripts for the Illustrator actions.

Comment: Illustrator can be scripted, but asking users here to make scripts for you is not fair. You can ask about scripting buy you need to show what script you have tried.  GDSE isn't a script writing service.

Comment: @BillyKerr No, I actually meant I know Javascript myself, I just did not know whether I could make scripts for actions, and if so, where I should import them. If I'm asking about scripting for a graphic design software in the incorrect graphic design stack exchange forum, my apologies... I'm still very new.

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/automation-scripts.html

Comment: Yes, thank you. I actually did go through that before asking here, but there's very little information / it was hard for me to understand and check whether or not that could include actions, so I instead asked here. I hope you don't mind. I also found my answer! Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED with using jimp npm on vscode with `setTimeout()`.

**I AM INCLUDING CODE BECAUSE THE TIPS FOR WRITING ANSWERS HERE SAYS TO BE SURE TO ANSWER THE QUESTION, PROVIDING DETAILS**

I am using this (someone helped me simplify my functions):

```js
const Jimp = require ('jimp');
// create a 64*64 image, with red=r green=g blue=b.
function createAndSave(r,g,b) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // convert rgb values to a rgba color code
        let colorInt = Jimp.rgbaToInt(r, g, b, 255);
        // create new image filled with color(r,g,b);
        new Jimp(64,64, colorInt, (err,image) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            // name the file with color hex code. replace '0x' with '#' to have css color code.
            let fileName = '0x'+('00000000'+new Number(colorInt).toString(16)).slice(-8,-2)+'.png';
            // write on disk
            image.write(fileName,(err,image) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                //return fileName.
                resolve(fileName);
            });
        })
    });
}

//3 loops to rule them all
async function createAll(){
    for (let r=0; r<256; r++) { // all reds
        for (let g=0; g<256; g++) { // all greens
            for (let b=0; b<256; b++) { // all blues
                await createAndSave(r,g,b);
            }
        }
    }
}

createAll();
```

but the first try caused a crash, most likely due to the loop running fast, so I am adding `setTimeout()` for every 256 times it goes through:

```js
const Jimp = require ('jimp');
// create a 64*64 image, with red=r green=g blue=b.
function createAndSave(r,g,b) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // convert rgb values to a rgba color code
        let colorInt = Jimp.rgbaToInt(r, g, b, 255);
        // create new image filled with color(r,g,b);
        new Jimp(64,64, colorInt, (err,image) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            // name the file with color hex code. replace '0x' with '#' to have css color code.
            let fileName = '0x'+('00000000'+new Number(colorInt).toString(16)).slice(-8,-2)+'.png';
            // write on disk
            image.write(fileName,(err,image) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                //return fileName.
                resolve(fileName);
            });
        })
    });
}

const sleep = async ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

//3 loops to rule them all
async function createAll(){
    for (let r=0; r<256; r++) { // all reds
        for (let g=0; g<256; g++) { // all greens
            for (let b=0; b<256; b++) { // all blues
                await createAndSave(r,g,b);
            }
            await sleep(1000);
        }
        await sleep(1000);
    }
}

createAll();
```

I ended up not using Adobe Illustrator but instead using the npm package Jimp. It takes time but is still much faster than manually creating these files. In the future, I still would like to know whether I can make scripts for Illustrator's actions or if there is any way I can add the steps to the actions so I would not have to manually create the artboards, but as of now, I (think) I have completed this part of my project. Thank you!

Comment: offcourse its faster if it takes you 10 seconds per item it takes several years to do this. But seriously though if you should start with some reasonable starting point. theres not much point in me showing how to lock you adobe account for months on end as your first project.

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely infeasible to do this in illustrator scripting engine. The engine is relatively slow, and it takes closer to a second per file save. So lets say for an argument that it takes a second per file, that would mean.

16 000 000 seconds ≈ 185 days,

of continnious script running. Now even if your script and disk activity would take just 100 ms it would still be 18 days of computer time. if you must use the computer for other stuff say a month.

So clearly there is room for spending a few days on learning better ways, like thinking do you really need this. Disk wise thats OK with a minimum allocation block of 2 kilobytes its still only 32 gigabytes of files. A lot of disk estate sure but not impossible.